# UDP socket set DontFragment (DF) field in outgoing packets - will it catch the ICMP "packet too large" respnses?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, udp, icmp

I'm using UDP socket to send data to a remote connection and i'd like to implement PMTUD (path mtu discovery) on top of it.

So I set the DF bit on the socket which trigger the appropriate bit in every outgoing packet.

When packet size is bigger than the path mtu, it suppose to receive ICMP response with the appropriate type (DF bit is set and packet is too big).

Since the socket is defined as UDP (here's how its defined using boost asio wrapper), I don't think it's suitable to catch ICMP responses since it's a different protocol.

```
  socket_ = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>(ioc);
```

Should I create an additional RAW/ICMP socket (dedicated for ICMP packets) in order to catch the ICMP responses ? for instance :

```
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP);
```

In this case, how can I know that the ICMP response relates to my specific UDP socket, and not to another connection ?

Thanks !

Comment: No. Just connect the socket. Then you will receive the ICMP errors as RST.

Comment: Hi and thanks for you comment. Perhaps you can answer me with a short code demonstation (using BSD sockets without wrappers) that handle the RST. from what I read in the related RFC "Reset Generation
  As a general rule, reset (RST) must be sent whenever a segment arrives
  which apparently is not intended for the current connection.  A reset
  must not be sent if it is not clear that this is the case."
so I'm not sure how it's connected to ICMP error responses

Comment: That's the TCP RFC. I'm talking about a UDP 'connection reset'. I should have said `ECONNRESET`, not `RST`. Perhaps you could just try adding the `connect()` line to connect the socket to the target and see what happens.

Comment: @Zohar81: See in [ip(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) the parts about IP_MTU and IP_MTU_DISCOVER. You can use this also with UDP to enable PMTU discovery on a connected socket with setsockopt IP_MTU_DISCOVER, wait until you get EMSGSIZE for larger packets  and then query what is discovered so far with getsockopt IP_MTU.